# Hide the origin (0 on x and y axis) in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm working on some code and I'd like to hide the origin (the zero on the x-axis, and the zero on the y-axis) from the graph. I've tried all possibilities I've seen, but when I get the list of labels they return empty, or they return with only a few values (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3) when the range is -10 - 10.

Also, is there any way to change the font of the ticks themselves to Computer Modern 10 (The LaTeX font?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the `0` on the axes could be done using a `FuncFormatter`. The function for this formatter would simply check if the label is 0 and return an empty string in that case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5,8)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)

func = lambda x, pos: "" if np.isclose(x,0) else x
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(func))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(func))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Marking this as the answer, however, would you also have a fix to my font issue? It's not allowing me to set my own font!

Comment: It would really be good to avoid asking two different things in the same quesiton. This is a very good example which shows why asking two questions at once is bad: You simply forgot to give a clear problem description for that issue. So are you using latex (usetex=True) or not? What is the problem? Have you tried to set the font and it's not working or do you not know how to set the font? Have you googled for that? If so, in how far are other questions on that not helping and so on.

Comment: You're totally right! I'll try to stick to two questions next time :).

I want my ticks to be in the font Computer Modern, but not RENDER in LaTeX. I've done every single StackOverflow suggestion I've seen from changing the rcParams at the beginning manually to using the update function, etc.