# Change font of tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

How can I change the font of matplotlib tick labels? I'd like to change it to Computer Modern 10 (called "cm" in matplotlib I believe), however, I don't want to **render** it in TeX. I've tried numerous ways of doing this, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score -3):

```
func = lambda x, pos: "" if np.isclose(x,0) else x
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(func))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(func))
```

Works in my case!

Comment: This is just [the answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661312/4124317) and has nothing to do with changing the font.