# Use specific TTF font file for tick labels in seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to change the font family of the tick labels of a specific axis to a certain font, defined in a `.ttf` file. I do not want to change this globally, only for the tick labels. Both matplotlib or seaborn specific instructions would do.

I'm not able to find instructions on how to do this. The approach sugggested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662342/change-font-of-tick-labels-in-matplotlib) is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the font (depends on your operating system). 
Then specify the font when setting the tick labels using the `fontname` argument.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax2.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(0, 1, 6), fontname='Suruma')
```

[image]

If you want to change existing tick-labels, you can set the fontname property of the text object, and redraw:

```
for text_obj in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    text_obj.set_fontname('Suruma')
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd hoped for a option that didn't require installing fonts to the system, but I get that that is probably not possible.

Comment: @gandreadis I didn't realize that was an important requirement. It is possible, just requires a bit more setup. See part 2 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574948/2912349).

Comment: Also, you can simply add the font to the matplotlib font folder, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47758634/2912349).